# Performing MLE using optim and optimParallel functions in R: improving speed and fixing an error

Tags: r, mle

I am using optimParallel function (a parallel version of gradient based optim) to implement a maximization task. The line of codes involving optimParellel are

```
library(parallel)
library(optimParallel)
mle<-optimParallel(parameter, loglik, gr=NULL, method="Nelder-Mead",    hessian=TRUE, x=X, y=Y)
```

The codes work well when I use optim function, however, it is very slow. For this reason, I tried to use optimParallel function as above but R throws the following erorr message

```
Error in stats::optim(par = par, fn = fg$f, gr = fg$g, method = method,    : 
'ndeps' is of the wrong length
```

First, I would like to know why this error occurs and how it could be fixed. Secondly, the aim is to make optim run faster so it would be helpful if anyone could suggest possible ways to achieve this. Many thanks

Comment: Please provide a (minimal) reproducible example.

Comment: If you think there is a bug in optimParallel, you can also send a reproducible example to the package maintainer or post it here: https://git.math.uzh.ch/florian.gerber/optimParallel/issues